# Continue script execute after PHP exec

Tags: php, shell

Im using PHPs `exec()` function to execute a `.bat` file but i have a problem. The whole site hangs waiting for a response from the exec command. My `.bat` file contains the following... `mstsc /v:192.168.1.1` the IP address is an example.

**My Code**

I have looked around a bit and tried adding `' > /dev/null &'` to my script but adding this stops the script from executing all together. Heres my full code: (this is in my laravel controller)

```
public function startRemoteDesktop(Request $request)
{
    $name = $request->input('name');
    $ip_address = $request->input('ip');
    $path = public_path() . '/files/bat_files/'. $name . '.bat';
    $contents = 'mstsc /v:' . $ip_address;

    if(File::exists($path))
    {
        return 'RDP Connection Currently In Use!';
    }

    File::put($path, $contents);
    exec($path);
    File::delete($path);

    exec($path . ' > /dev/null &'); //Alternative exec command that ive tried
}
```

**Note**

Without `' > /dev/null &'` added to my exec code it works fine but obviously it hangs meaning i cant do anything else with PHP until i close the RDP connection.

**Question**

How can i open the RDP from my exec command (or other php command) without making it pause all PHP scripts from executing?

Comment: what do you mean by "adding this stops the script from executing all together." adding `&` to the end of command will make you run the command in the background , what are you expecting after executing the command ?

Comment: @HassanAhmed when the remote desktop application starts my web page does not execute any further PHP commands until its closed,

Comment: and how do you wrote your command with `> /dev/null &` ? , may you update the example with full command code

Comment: @HassanAhmed Ive updated my question

Comment: what's your server operation system please ?

Comment: @HassanAhmed Its windows 8.1

Comment: there is no '>/dev/null' in windows , it's only in linux based servers , so this won't help you , and the `&` operator has different meaning in windows , in linux this will run your progress in background , in windows it's used in separating commands . i think [this post](http://serverfault.com/questions/9038/run-a-bat-file-in-a-scheduled-task-without-a-window) would help

Comment: @HassanAhmed Ah i didnt notice that this was trying to use linux commands, this is actually a huge step forward i didnt know adding my OS was important to the help from the PHP command

Comment: @HassanAhmed Last thing, if i had this script on my server, would the linux commands then execute seen as my server is linux based

Comment: i think the problem will be that `.bat` extension is a windows operation system extension , i'm afraid that you will not be able to run it easily from your linux based server , although there are some posts may help in this context , http://www.linux.org/threads/running-windows-batch-files-on-linux.7610/

Answer (score 0):

I found that using `popen($path, 'r');` allows PHP to continue script executing without waiting for the current `.bat` file to send a response

Comment: Nice, but remember to delete the .bat file with code inside the .bat file. Because if you don't wait untils it's end you will deleting the .bat file within the php and you won't detect if the process it's running or not in the next run of the php.

Comment: So you fixed it? If the popen solved it for you I will delete my answer.